# How to copy incoming and outgoing email to another account in Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

What I want is that all emails sent to/from `user1@example.com` are copied to `user2@example.com`. The configuration solution must not be modifiable by `user1` (due to that requirement I think any solution that includes the creation of a  filter in the `user1` account won't suit, unless a filter in `user1` account that `user1` can't delete), and if the configuration is hidden from `user1` all the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1346934?hl=en&ref_topic=2683824) is the doc to do that.

> The Content compliance setting enables you to specify what action to
>   perform for messages based on predefined sets of words, phrases, text
>   patterns, or numerical patterns. The content compliance setting scans
>   messages for content that matches one or more rules that you configure
>   within the setting. You can choose whether these messages are rejected
>   or delivered with modifications -- for example, to notify others when
>   the content of a message matches the rules that you set.

Comment: links can rot. Please quote the key parts of the links in the answer.